# read numerical value from file and place it as an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

i have a text file like this

**.txt**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

and i would like to view this as an array in python  this is what i have so far

**python file**

```
 file_board = open('index.txt')
 board = file_board.read().split(',')
 print board
 print len(board)
```

**output**

```
['[[1', ' 2', ' 3]', ' [4', ' 5', ' 6]', ' [7', ' 8', ' 9]]\n']
9
list index out of range
```

so what i want todo is some how make this in to a 2D array  for manipulation

**Note** I would like to do this without any external libraries, build in libraries are fine

by the way i would like to write this back to a new file
in the format of

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: what is the difference between your new file and your old file?

Comment: are you sure you get the output as described? (it should be `['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8', ' 9\n']` instead). You also might start writing `print(foo)` instead of `print foo`, as the latter notation is no longer valid in Python-3 (and Python-2 will [not be maintained past 2020](https://pythonclock.org/) - start writing Python3 code *now*)

Comment: i would do some calculations and change those numbers later on @d_kennetz

Comment: but they are already in that format, .txt literally looks the exact same as your last line

Comment: Do you want an `array` or a `list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this using index slicing and zip:

```
infile = open('./Desktop/nums.txt')

board = infile.read().strip('\\n').split(',')
# the numbers are in string format at this point
# board ['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8', ' 9']
board_array = [[int(x),int(y),int(z)] for x,y,z in zip(board[::3], board[1::3], board[2::3])]
```

output:

```
>>> board_array
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I do not understand what you want from your output but this will generate a 2D array of ints from your text file and it will strip that new line character `'\n'`